# Delphi TThread under ARC (iOS) not being released

Tags: ios, delphi, automatic-ref-counting, delphi-xe4

What is a proper way to terminate a thread using Delphi for iOS under ARC management?

Take this simple example:

```
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FThread: TMyThread;
  public
  end;

{ TMyThread }
destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin

  ShowMessage('Destroy');

  inherited Destroy;

end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin

  Sleep(5000);

end;

{ TForm2 }
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FThread := TMyThread.Create(TRUE);
  FThread.FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;
  FThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(FThread.RefCount.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FThread := nil;
end;
```

Ok, pressing Button1 will spawn a thread. After thread is started, if you click Button2 it will display a RefCount value of 3!! Well, 1 is the reference to my FThread variable, and there are 2 additional references that TThread creates internally... I have digged into source code and found that RefCount is increased here:

```
constructor TThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);

  ErrCode := BeginThread(nil, @ThreadProc, Pointer(Self), FThreadID);
  if ErrCode <> 0 then
    raise EThread.CreateResFmt(@SThreadCreateError, [SysErrorMessage(ErrCode)]);
  {$ENDIF POSIX}
```

And here:

```
function ThreadProc(Thread: TThread): Integer;
var
  FreeThread: Boolean;
begin
  TThread.FCurrentThread := Thread;
```

Well... After thread is finished (In my case, after 5 seconds), the RefCount will decrease to 2 (Because I have set FreeOnTerminate to TRUE, but if I don´t set FreeOnTerminate to TRUE, the RefCount will still be 3).

See the problem? Thread is never finished and destructor is never called, if I call `FThread := nil`, then, the RefCount should decrease from 2 to 1 (Or from 3 to 2 in case `FreeOnTerminate = FALSE`), and thread is never released under ARC...

Maybe I´m missing something because I´m used to working with threads with no ARC... So, what am I missing here? Or is there a bug in TThread implementation under ARC?

Maybe this definition of TThread

```
private class threadvar
  FCurrentThread: TThread;
```

should be something like

```
private class threadvar
  [Weak] FCurrentThread: TThread;
```

Comment: Isn't `FCurrentThread` released in the destructor?

Comment: FCurrentThread is a class threadvar variable of TThread, it is not a variable from the instance, but a class variable from TThread. This variable is never niled. Judging by the code, it should change if I spawn another thread... but I haven´t tested

So... My thread destructor is never called

Comment: It won't change by spawning another thread. Each OS thread gets its own version of that variable because it's a threadvar. It's the TThread equivalent of GetCurrentThreadID.

Comment: It's a shame you haven't got a complete program in the form of a console app to demo the issue. All that GUI just gets in the way, in my view.

Comment: David, I can make that console app, if that helps...

Comment: From the source, I can see that `FCurrentThread` is never set to `nil`. I also see that `ThreadWrapper` pairs a `New` with `FreeMem` which is clearly bogus. `New` goes with `Dispose`. And since the thing that was allocated contained a reference to your thread, there could be a leak there. But since `Self` is cast to `Pointer`, that should be a weak ref. I'd cut it down to a minimal sample and submit a QC report.

Comment: Oh, David, I can´t make a console app... It is Delphi for iOS, a Console app in Win32/64 or OSX does not implement ARC....

Comment: Well.. I think I will fill up a QC report :)

Comment: OK, maybe not a console app. But all the code in a single file. No external resources (whatever .dfm files are calling in FMX) and so on. Just a file that starts `program` and has code executed between a top level `begin` and `end`.

Comment: QC #116460 filled :) Now lets wait for Emb. answer

Comment: The real bug is that `ThreadProc()` does not nil `TThread.FCurrentThread` after the thread finishes running. That accounts for one dangling reference, at least. But I can't see why the refcount would be going up to 3. The `BeginThread()` code does not do anything that should be touching the refcount at all.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging in qc the following issues and workaround show up:

**Thread parameters should be passed as `const`**

```
function ThreadProc(Thread: TThread): Integer;  <<-- pass_by_reference pushes
var                                                  up the ref_count.
  FreeThread: Boolean;
begin
  TThread.FCurrentThread := Thread;
```

Had you passed it as `const` the ref_count would have not gone up to 3.
Normally this is not a problem, because the ref_count gets decreased on exit of the function, but here:

> [the function epilog is never exectued because pthread_exit() jumps out of the code](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116460).

This is only part of the solution though, quite a bit more needs to be done...

**[Full workaround by Dave Nottage](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116460)**

> After much fiddling around, I've come up with this potential workaround:

Make these mods to the Classes unit:
Change:

```
function ThreadProc(Thread: TThread): Integer;
```

to:

```
function ThreadProc(const Thread: TThread): Integer;
```

and add:

```
TThread.FCurrentThread := nil;
```

after this line:

```
if FreeThread then Thread.Free;
```

Override `DoTerminate` in the TThread descendant, thus:

```
procedure TMyThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  try
    inherited;
  finally
    __ObjRelease;
  end;
end;
```

Call the thread thus:

```
FMyThread.Free; // This will do nothing the first time around, since the reference will be nil
FMyThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
// DO NOT SET FreeOnTerminate
FMyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminate;
FMyThread.Resume;
```

> This (at least for me, on the device) results in the thread being destroyed on subsequent calls.
>
> NOTE: Under ARC conditions, *never* declare a reference to a thread locally, because when it falls out of scope, the thread is destroyed and the Execute method is never called, not to mention other problems it causes.